# What are the exit codes in the RPM binary?

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, rpm, suse

Each time `rpm` command returns different exit codes. For example- In case of failed dependency sometimes `echo $?` gives 1 and sometime 5. Can someone explain this?

Comment: I cant find anything about exit codes in `man`

Comment: Right, it doesn't mention. Not very hidden though I found this `Yes. Unfortunately, it's a very short list: the exit code equals the number
of failed packages, capped at 255.` https://www.redhat.com/archives/rpm-list/2005-July/msg00071.html

Comment: Is this the same for all the errors returned by rpm? Suppose sometimes the error is `failed dependency` and sometimes `erase failed`. Is exit code of both of these errors is equal to the number of failed packages?

Answer (score 0):

It's the amount of things that failed for any reason,

```
$ rpm -i $(seq 1 3); echo "Failed with $?"
error: open of 1 failed: No such file or directory
error: open of 2 failed: No such file or directory
error: open of 3 failed: No such file or directory
Failed with 3
```